# Error 500 PHP AngularJS

Tags: php, angularjs, servidor

Acabo de subir mi proyecto a un servidor, pero resulta que obtengo una respuesta del servidor (Status:500), esta es una consulta breve en mi pagina de inicio con respecto a las ciudades:

> He leído al respecto y he encontrado que puede ser por causas del
>   **.htacces** pero aun no lo he implementado, así que descarto esa opción, y el log tampoco retorna error alguno

```
<?php
  header("Context-type: application/json;");

  require '../conexion.php';
  $mysqli->set_charset('utf8');
  $resultadoConsultaCiudad = $mysqli->query("SELECT cdes.id_ciudad,
                                                      cdes.ciudad,
                                                    dpto.id_departamento,
                                                    dpto.departamento
                                                FROM ciudades cdes
                                                INNER JOIN departamento dpto
                                                ON dpto.id_departamento = cdes.id_departamento");

  $dataSalidaCiudad = array();

  while ($row = $resultadoConsultaCiudad->fetch_assoc())
  {
    $dataSalidaCiudad[] = $row;
  }

  echo json_encode($dataSalidaCiudad);
?>
```

Este es la parte del cliente (AngularJS):

```
//FUNCION QUE SE ENCARGA DE OBTENER LOS DATOS DE LA TABLA CIUDAD
  $scope.importarDatosCiudad = function()
  {
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'mainApp/Read/consultarCiudades.php'
      })
      .then(function successCallback(datosCiudad)
      {
        $scope.tableCiudades = datosCiudad.data;

      },function errorCallback(datosCiudad)
      {
        console.log("Error, al tratar de traer los datoss", datosCiudad)
      });
  }
  $scope.importarDatosCiudad();
```

resultado:

> {data: "", status: 500, config: {…}, statusText: "Internal Server
>   Error", headers: ƒ} config : {method: "GET", transformRequest:
>   Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), jsonpCallbackParam: "callback",
>   paramSerializer: ƒ, …} data : "" headers : ƒ (d) status : 500
>   statusText : "Internal Server Error"
>   **proto** : Object

Comment: Cuando en mis proyectos me aparece este error suele ser por que hay un error en el código que impide el flujo normal de éste. Has probado la consulta directamente en la base de datos para comprobar que es correcta? E ir comprobando el resultado de cada variable así como el json devuelto para comprobar que todo fluye como debe.

Comment: La consulta funciona correctamente, y me he dirigido a cada uno de mis archivos que tienen una consulta general sin requerir un uso de session y obtengo el mismo resultado. Dentro del LocalHost no me genera error alguno hasta que compre el dominio para probar mi proyecto

Comment: Has probado a hacer que se imprima la descripción del error para poder ver un poco mejor que es lo que sucede?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No puedo darte una respuesta directa de qué te está fallando en el código, te invito a que actives los errores de `php` para averiguar qué y dónde está fallando. Puedes hacer esto fácilmente añadiendo este código al principio de tu `.php`.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

Recuerda que el ambiente de desarrollo es conveniente tener los errores y advertencias activadas, sin embargo en el entorno de producción lo mejor es tenerlos ocultos y poder revisarlos desde el log.

Puedes activar los errores de forma predeterminada (para que no tengas que escribir el código de arriba en todas partes) en tu php.ini cambiando `display_errors` de Off a On.

```
display_errors = On
```